# Print an xlsx file with charts/pictures to pdf on Linux using Python

Tags: python, excel, linux, pdf, printing

I've read following and many more:

1. [print xlsx file from command line using ghostscript and libreoffice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437331/print-xlsx-file-from-command-line-using-ghostscript-and-libreoffice)
2. [Print chosen worksheets in excel files to pdf in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683376/print-chosen-worksheets-in-excel-files-to-pdf-in-python)
3. [Python Converting an Excel file (.xlsx) to a PDF (.pdf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62391152/python-converting-an-excel-file-xlsx-to-a-pdf-pdf)
4. [Python - Converting XLSX to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52326782/python-converting-xlsx-to-pdf)
5. [Can you hard print an .xlsx file on Linux with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67577755/can-you-hard-print-an-xlsx-file-on-linux-with-python)
   (unasnwered)
6. [Python library to open existing .xlsx workbook with charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46386143/python-library-to-open-existing-xlsx-workbook-with-charts)

---

- I have an xlsx file that contains lots of charts, tables and pictures (png watermarks inserted into the excel sheet as picture). E.g. [see this sample template](https://templates.office.com/en-us/fitness-tracker-tm16400940).
- I want to print this to a pdf.
- I'm on Linux and preferably want to use Python.

Closest I came was using `libreoffice` as described in answer #1 (Command used: `libreoffice --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf ./Book1.xlsx`) in list above. But all the text/formatting is messed up (whether I open the pdf file on Linux where I printed it or on Windows where I created the original xlsx file):

[image]

Same xlsx file printed on Windows using Excel App's print to pdf:
[image]

File does look ok when I open it in libreoffice-calc on linux:
[image]

Comment: Does the file look OK when you open the it with LibreOffice manually?

Comment: @Bodo, yes, unfortunately it does look almost OK. I added a pic to the post.

Comment: The [answer to #1](https://askubuntu.com/a/437346/1186757) suggests two commands. Please show the command you used. Can you share an xlsx file to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Bodo, added "Command used" and link to a "Sample template" that you can use. You can use any excel with a chart. Only difference is mine was simpler and had just one sheet.

Comment: @Bodo, just checking in case you had ideas..? Thanks!